# Curious on Starting Page (ASP.NET related)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm new to Web Page development, and my first question always is - do we normally declare a starting page whenever designing web pages?

Sometimes I get confused when building a web application in VS, I notice that when working on built web apps, we can't normally do the "Start Debugging" and a new window will appear for the application to be debugged. Instead, we normally go to the browser and type an address of the "starting page".

I'm relatively new to web page development, and I've been always curious why do we do that and how can we easily follow which page to start with?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that Default Document for any website is going to apply. In MVC's case, http://localhost:####/ is going to invoke the default controller and action registered in the Global.asax which is HomeController => Index.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the start page for your web application:

1. right click on your web app project,
2. select `properties`,
3. choose the `Web` tab,
4. click `specific page` and browse for the page you want to start with

This technique also lets you pass `querystring` parameters to your starting page and to specify logical `routes` in an `MVC` application - e.g.

- /Home/User/bobbyGreen <--- where the actual page is /Views/User/index.aspx
- /FindUser?id=bobbygreen <---- passes the id parameter to the page on startup

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio IDE, if you are working with an ASP.NET web application/website, you can right click on a page and select "`Set as Start page`". If it is an MVC project, you can not do this. But you can go to the project properties and Set it under "web" tab of your project properties.